# Add more text to panda plot labels

Tags: python, pandas, label

I have a dataframe to which I want to precisely modify the label when using df.plot(). Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

When plotting this dataframe it shows the name of the columns as labels, but I will like to add more text at the top of that label in `LATEX` format, for instance `$V_{sd}$`. At the end I want my label to look like:

```
(transparent) $V_{sd}$
(blue) a
(orange) b
(green) c
```

What is written inside the parenthesis is the color of the label/line which I want to precisely control as well.

One way to do this is using matplotlib.pyplot.plot and make an empty plot with the extra label and then plot each column/row one by one, but I wonder if there is an easier way to do it with pandas since I have a bunch of dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
df.plot(color=['b','orange','green'])
plt.legend(title='$V_{sd}$')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that plt.legend() have a title parameter. Thanks.